# can bootstrap js be downloaded in a modular way for different bootstrap components?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I'm new to bootstrap and I need to put together a responsive grid based on bootstrap v4 alpha.  I'm working on an existing website which has the following dir structure:

```
js > vendor > bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.4 > 
-- modal.js
-- tooltip.js
-- [carousel.js]
-- etc
```

I downloaded bootstrap v4 for my own personal site earlier today and the downloaded zip only had a single js file as opposed to several modular js files. Is there a different download package for bootstrap v4 that contains a collection of modular js files as opposed to a singular monolithic js file?  Or is the bootstrap folder/file structure in the existing website that I need to update suspect?

Comment: They're available on [GitHub](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v4-dev/js/src), but I don't know about downloading from the Bootstrap website.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You just have to download the source file not the normal download. https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/#source-files